# Return not working correctly in jQuery

Tags: jquery, function, iterator, return, each

I've got a bunch of `ul`'s, and each `ul` contains a bunch of `input`'s.  The function in question takes a string from a "search box" and tries to find it within each `ul` by searching each of the `input`'s that are in said `ul`.  Each `input` that DOESN'T have the searched string is FLAGGED.  The function counts the number of FLAGGED `input`'s, and if the number of FLAGGED `input`'s in the `ul` is equal to the TOTAL number of `input`'s in the `ul`, then it can be determined that the searched string does not exist in that `ul` at all, and said `ul` should be given a class of `hide-this`.

```
function findString(subject){
   var increment = 0;
   //If string cannot be found, highlight input
   if ($(subject).val().indexOf("s") == -1){
       $(subject).css("background-color", "#ff0000");
       increment = 1;  
   }
   console.log("Increment is " + increment + "!");
   //Return value by which to increment error count (can be 1 or 0)
   return increment;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    //When new term is entered into searchbox
    $('#query-input').bind('input', function(){

        //For each UL in table
        $(".big-table ul:not(.big-table-headers)").each(function(i){

            //Count total number of inputs in UL
            var inputCount = $(this).find("input").length;
            var errorCount = 0;
            console.log("input count is: " + inputCount);

            //Then for each input in UL, try to find string
            $(this).find("input").each(function(){
                //Increment errorCount based on return value of findString()
                errorCount = errorCount + $(findString($(this)));
            });
            console.log("errorCount is " + errorCount + "!");

            /*If the number of inputs in the UL containing string is the same as
            the total number of inputs, then no inputs in the UL contain this string, 
            and the entire ul should be hidden*/
            if(errorCount == inputCount){
                $(this).addClass("hide-this");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The `findString()` function works well and does identify each `input` that doesn't have the string, but when I try to return a numeric value (1 or 0) from that function to the main function, `findString()` instead returns an object, which I of course cannot use in any mathematical operations.  I suspect it has something to do with using `.each()` iterators, but I'm not sure.  Does anyone have any ideas?

**NOTE**: *I am forcing the function to use a string of "s" for test purposes, so it's not actually taking the direct input from the search box, but the function is being called by the search box.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't wrap a call to `jQuery` arount `findString`. It should be:

```
errorCount = errorCount + findString($(this));
```

Your code is trying to add a jQuery object to `errorCount`, instead of the number returned by `findString`.

Comment: Yes, that seems to have taken care of it.  Thanks!